# Two Network Cards Routing Inbound and Outbound Traffic Windows 2012

Tags: windows, networking, routing

What I am trying to accomplish here is to use my two Gigabit LAN cards and have Windows route all inbound traffic on one LAN card and then route all outbound traffic on the other. Is this possible, Google did not turn up anything useful today. Basically I want Gigabit in and out of my file server I have setup.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?  Are you wanting it to do routing or are you saying you want the traffic coming inbound on one interface  to return on the other network interface (which by the way isn't a very useful idea)

Comment: I guess the question is why? because there may be better options.

Comment: I guess my logic behind it was to have use my two LAN cards and have a full Gigabit coming in and a full Gigabit going out. If this isn't useful then I just may have some suggestions with my setup. My goal is to use as much bandwidth as possible without affecting the end user performance.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

You don't seem to be aware of the distinction between half-duplex and full-duplex.  Most modern networks run full-duplex (i.e. their are two channels, one for inbound and one for outbound traffic).  Unless you are using a really old network device (e.g. a hub instead of a switch), you should already be running at full duplex.  So you should already have a full 1Gbps both in and out with just one NIC.

CJ

Comment: So I have seen servers that have four NICs and they stated that two are for inbound and two for outbound. How is this possible? I have even seen five, two for inbound and two for outbound and one for internal traffic.

Comment: It could be that they are using asymetric routing in order to achieve some specific effect.  For example, they might have an expensive firewall for inbound traffic and not want to use its capacity on outbound traffic.  It is hard to know without a specific example.

Comment: You do not need aymetric routing to get a full 1GBps up/down, you just need full duplex.  See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/335979

Answer (score 0):

Gigabit Ethernet is full duplex. You get 1Gb/s simultaneously in both directions from a single port. If your switch supports link aggregation you can bond the two ports and get 2Gb/s in & out.